# Ornstein Uhlenbeck with correlated paths

Tags: matlab, mean, revert, montecarlo

I'm trying to do a MCS on a spread option, where one leg of the spread option is dependent on four underlyings. So I found the code on goddard http://www.goddardconsulting.ca/matlab-monte-carlo-assetpaths-corr.html
and modified it to handle more than two assets because it didn't work with more than two.
My code looks like this:

```
% do a Cholesky factorization on the correlation matrix
R = chol(corr); 
% pre-allocate the output
S = nan(steps+1,nsims,nAssets);  
% generate uncorrelated random sequence
x = randn(steps,size(corr,2));
% correlate the sequences
ep = x*R;

% generate correlated random sequences and paths
for idx = 1:nsims

    A = repmat( drift*dt,steps,1 );
    B = ep*diag(sig)*sqrt(dt);
    [s1 s2] = size (B);
    A = reshape(A, s1,s2);  % A and B have to be reshaped to fit
    % Generate potential paths
    S(:,idx,:) = [ones(1,nAssets); cumprod(exp(A + B)) ]*diag(S0);
end

% If only one simulation then remove the unitary dimension
if nsims==1
    S = squeeze(S);
end
```

and plotting it all I get a visually useful result. That is, I can use the generated paths as input to the "leg" I need for the option calculation.
 My quite ridiculous problem is: I don't actually understand what

```
S(:,idx,:) = [ones(1,nAssets); cumprod(exp(A + B)) ]*diag(S0);
```

is doing. Could some one explain? I have iterated through it but it doesn't get any clearer. SO are the four end values of my four underlyings that I use as start value for the simulations.

What I actually would have preferred to do, as it worked well with non-correlated paths and I understand the matlab code, is to simply create a model with HWV in matlab, calculate drift and long-term mean and other needed factors, and in some way apply the cholesky to the wiener process, and then generate the correlated paths instead of as before uncorrelated paths. I woulf need to pass the random numbers, multiplied by the cholesky in order to get them correlated, to the matlab function "simulate", but I can't find out how to do that.

%%% EDIT SEPTEMBER 26 %%%

Ok, I finally managed to create an HWV-object for my 4 asstes, passing all kinds of vectors and arrays and matrices of the right sizes...
This is the correlation matrix I passed:

(order NATGAS GASOIL FUELOIL EURUSD)

```
    1.0000    0.8819    0.8118   -0.5096
    0.8819    1.0000    0.9744   -0.3065
    0.8118    0.9744    1.0000   -0.2832
   -0.5096   -0.3065   -0.2832    1.0000
```

As you can see, obviously the eurusd fx rate is negatively correlated with the hydrocarbons.

So why are the simulated assets paths practically identical?
[image]

The EURUSD should be completely different, as when I do the correlated GBM using the code above.

Comment: That looks like the integral in "Equation 1" on the link you've quoted. Or is there something unclear about the MATLAB syntax/functions used?

Comment: Yes I do understand it's the equation...somwhow... But yes, the three dim matrix with a cumprod in it is hard for me to digest. EDIT: once I completely understand the syntax I can transform the whole thing into an ornstein uhlenbeck.

Comment: The [`hmv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/hwv.html) function has a correlation option. Also, despite the fact that the example code you linked to uses it, you probably shouldn't use a variable call `corr` as you may actually want to use Matlab's `corr` function.

Comment: MCS = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCS - Is that right?